# Set Default date 1 year out from insert date

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have a table with the following layout:

```
create table x (
   insert_date date DEFAULT sysdate,
   last_update_date date,
   expiration_date date
)
```

If I write to this table the value for insert_date will be obviously the exact time in which it was written. My Question is, is there a way to set a default value for expiration_date that is literally just "sysdate + 1 year" ?

Comment: You will probably have to use a trigger.

Comment: Since insert_date and expiration_date are what I would call audit data, I would use a trigger to enforce valid values in both columns AND prevent any application developer from either forgetting them or updating them.  Only you can tell if you are applying the correct amount of paranoia in the safe keeping of your data.

Comment: Do either of you know what that trigger would look like? Thanks for your input by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `DEFAULT SYSDATE` , you can write a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` to take the passed date value or date of execution if it is `null`.

```
SET DEFINE OFF
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_x BEFORE  INSERT ON x
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
:new.insert_date := NVL(:new.insert_date,SYSDATE);
:new.expiration_date := :new.insert_date + INTERVAL '1' YEAR;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603) function.

Example:

```
create table x2 (
   insert_date date DEFAULT sysdate,
   LAST_UPDATE_DATE date,
   EXPIRATION_DATE date DEFAULT add_months(sysdate, 12)
);

insert into x2 (LAST_UPDATE_DATE) values (TO_DATE('2017-11-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
commit;
```

Here is an example using a trigger.

```
create or replace trigger x2_TX 
    before insert on x2 for each row
begin
   :new.EXPIRATION_DATE := ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 12);
end;
```

[Stilgar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4242042/stilgar) has a great point about my first example not being "developer safe" relative to the second.  I would have suggested the former in the interest of simplicity, now I would do what is considered best practice on your team.

Comment: These are great points! So thanks for all of them. As for as security of data, we've locked down some actions from the API side of things. I tried utilizing this trigger, however when it is invoked it fails. The one below works, so I will be accepting that one. Thank you all for your inputs!!!